# How to keep the selected item?

Tags: javascript, selected

I have a menu, when the user clicks on an item in it, `Open(obj)` function runs and opens a "bid" `div` which has other elements inside. When a different item is clicked, the last visible `div` should get `display:"none"`, and the new one become `display:"block"`.

My problem is, that I just want this div to change when a different item is clicked, not when the user clicks anywhere else on the screen!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would bind to all of your menu items. The function will first hide all of the divs and then simply show the one you need to.

Comment: Its a term used to desribe hooking an action to an element or set of elements. Look into jQuery and research bind.